# How to fix pgAdmin4 connection refused error

Tags: postgresql, centos, virtualbox

I'm getting this error when attempting to setup a new server on pgAdmin4:

```
Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "192.168.210.146" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I have postgres 12.7 running on CentOS 8 inside a virtual box 6.1 VM which is running on my Windows 10 21H1 laptop. I can connect to the OS using putty and the CentOS web client just fine.

Here is some network info via the CentOS web client terminal:

```
# nmap localhost         
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-07-14 16:59 PDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000014s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
5432/tcp open  postgresql
9090/tcp open  zeus-admin

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.68 seconds

 netstat -tlpn          
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/systemd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      954/sshd            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN   972/postmaster      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37753         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN    1620/cockpit-bridge 

# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp0s3
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client postgresql ssh
  ports: 5432/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 
# 
# ifconfig
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.210.146  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 192.168.211.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fecb:8d2d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:cb:8d:2d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4704  bytes 512333 (500.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3757  bytes 2510585 (2.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 7252  bytes 2161674 (2.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7252  bytes 2161674 (2.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

In the PgAdmin setup server screen I'm using the ip address listed above of 192.168.210.146, user postgres and its password, port 5432 and the database is set to postgres.

I get this same error trying to establish odbc and jdbc connections from my laptop but I'm not sure what in the postgres environment needs to be fixed.I did add 1 entry the pg_hba.conf file as shown below, but that didn't help:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    all             all             192.168.210.146/32      trust #added;not helping
```

Is there another file or setting that needs to be fixed?

Thanks.

Comment: Check if `listen_addresses` in `postgresql.conf` is set to listen on 192.168.210.146. Looks like it only listens on 127.0.0.1.

Comment: How is networking configured on VB?

Comment: jjanes, I'm using the bridged adapter on network adapter 1.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to first un-comment the listen_address entry in postgresql.conf and then set it to the necessary ip number. Everything connects just fine now. Thanks